# Running astro cli inside a Jenkins build agent running as a POD in an Azure AKS Kubrenetes Cluster

Tags: astronomer

I am building a CI/CD pipeline and am trying to leverage Azure AKS for most of the CI/CD tooling, such as Jenkins, Kaniko etc.

However, when I tried to run "astro dev start", it is trying to find docker.sock, which is not available in AKS Managed Cluster.

```
root@ubuntu:/# astro version
Astro CLI Version: 1.19.2
root@ubuntu:/# mkdir Astro-Airflow && cd Astro-Airflow
root@ubuntu:/Astro-Airflow # pwd
/Astro-Airflow
root@ubuntu:/Astro-Airflow# astro dev init
Initializing Astro project
Pulling Airflow development files from Astro Runtime 9.1.0
Initialized empty Astro project in /Astro-Airflow
root@ubuntu:/Astro-Airflow# astro dev start
Error: error creating docker-compose project: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
root@ubuntu:/Astro-Airflow#
```

I would hate to create a VM with docker installed just to run just astro cli commands.

Can someone tell me what are my options? I am not familiar with Astronomer at all.